# Do I need to close handles to standard I/O after CreateProcess?

Tags: winapi, createprocess

I use the following `STARTUPINFO` structure in my call to `CreateProcess`. Do I need to call `CloseHandle` on `hStdError` and `hStdInput` after the process ends?

```
startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
startupInfo.cb = sizeof(si);
startupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
startupInfo.hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
startupInfo.hStdOutput =  NULL;
startupInfo.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
startupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't open those handles (that's not what `GetStdHandle`
does), you don't need to close them (maybe you *want* to close them
for some other reason, but it's unlikely). (Note: even if you *did*
open the handles, you don't have to wait for the process to exit
before you close them: once they are inherited, closing them in parent
process has no effect on the child).

Note that `hStdOutput` should be `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` instead of
`NULL`: that's the convention for passing the absence of a handle in `STARTUPINFO`.

Comment: I'd clarify that using `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` for the absence of a handle is the convention *for `STARTUPINFO`*.  It's not necessarily true in general.

Comment: But https://github.com/rprichard/win32-console-docs says std handles are copied as-is from hStd handles, and are set to NULLs when there should be no handle. It even says INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE std handles can cause a bug in Windows XP–8. @jamesdlin

Comment: @lcosie My comment was about clarifying a statement in an earlier version of this answer.  Regardless, [the documentation for `STARTUPINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfoa) specifies `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.  That is the *intended* behavior and is what applications should follow.  Whether some versions of Windows have a buggy implementation is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

To the question "do you need to?" - the simple answer is "no". 
When a process ends all handles connected to it are destroyed in Windows OSs.. if you are creating a process within a process (I don't even want to try that in C, but it's quite simple in C#) then it would be safer to make sure the child process cleans up after itself before (or on-) termination.

A way to test this would be to try and access your handle after you've terminated your child process in your parent process.